# Putting an arrow next to table

Tags: tables, arrows

I have a table. Each row in that table represents data at a certain point of time. Lower rows represent data for later times.

To illustrate this, I'd like to draw an arrow at the side (which doesn't really matter) of the table, pointing downwards, labelled with something like "time".

How would I do this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use `\Downarrow` to put a double arrow, or `\downarrow` for a single arrow. Applying a `\left ... \right` will allow it to be scaled to the height of the table.

The text can be added via `\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{time}` from [the `graphicx` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/graphicx).

[image]

### Notes:

- Assuming you only want the arrow on the left, then you will need to ensure that you replace the `\right\downarrow` with `\right.` at the end of the table. Similarly, replace the `\left\Downarrow` with `\left.` if you only want the arrow on the right..

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
$\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{time}%
\left\Downarrow% Use `\left.` if don't want arrow on this side.
\begin{tabular}{r r}
 1:00 & 2 \\
 3:00 & 4 \\
 5:00 & 6 \\
 7:00 & 8 \\
 8:00 & 10 \\
\end{tabular}
\right\downarrow%  Use `\right.` if don't want arrow on this side.
\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{time}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Very elegant! Upvoted this. :)

Comment: Is it possible to do the same at the top/bottom of the table with left/right arrows?

Comment: @DurandAL I recommend you post a new question. I personally would use the `\tikzmark`solution as shown in the other answer as that would be a lot more flexible.

Answer (score 8):

The following code contains two options; the first one doesn't use any special symbol, simply adds `/time(incr.)` to the column header to indicate an increasing time sequence order. The second one is a `TikZ` based solution:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\newcommand\tikzmark[1]{%
  \tikz[overlay,remember picture] \coordinate (#1);}

\begin{document}

\noindent\begin{tabular}{lc}
\toprule
head1 & data/time(incr.) \\
\midrule
text & 3 \\
text & 2 \\
text & 1 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\vspace{1cm}

\noindent\begin{tabular}{lc}
\toprule
head1 & data \\
\midrule
text & 3\tikzmark{start}\\
text & 2 \\
text & 1\tikzmark{end} \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
    \draw[->] let \p1=(start), \p2=(end) in ($(\x1,\y1)+(0.8,0.2)$) -- node[label=right:time] {} ($(\x1,\y2)+(0.8,0)$);
  \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution with `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`.

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{book}
\usepackage{nicematrix,tikz,booktabs}

\begin{document}

\NiceMatrixOptions{nullify-dots,xdots/horizontal-labels}

\begin{NiceTabular}{cc}[first-row,last-col]
\toprule
head1 & date \\
\midrule
text & 3 & \Vdots[line-style={solid,->}]^{\text{time}}\\
text & 2 \\
text & 1 \\
\bottomrule
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

You can as many rows as you want without changing the code for the arrow.

[image: Output of the above code]