# How to add caption to a table with arrow next to it?

Tags: tables, math-mode, tabularx, arrows

I have a table as described [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/60626/228340).

It has a \Downarrow on the left side.

I would like to add a caption to this, but I have had no luck due to the whole tabular environment being contained in math mode ($...$).

Comment: First of: always provide code (full minimal example). Then everyone know what you are doing. Secondly: you can only add captions inside a floating env (or use `\captionof` from the caption package). Since you show no code we have no idea what you are doing.

Answer (score 3):

You tried to encapsulate the `table` environment around it like this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}\centering
$\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{time}%
\left\Downarrow% Use `\left.` if don't want arrow on this side.
\begin{tabular}{r r}
 1:00 & 2 \\
 3:00 & 4 \\
 5:00 & 6 \\
 7:00 & 8 \\
 8:00 & 10 \\
\end{tabular}
\right\downarrow%  Use `\right.` if don't want arrow on this side.
\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{time}$
\caption{test}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

This yields for me:
[image: table screenshot]

Comment: Thank you, I realised my problem. My code was identical to the link I provided, except for that I had two tabular environments side-by-side enclosed in double $$.

Comment: You are welcome. Next time, when asking a question here, you should post a MWE as @daleif suggested.

Comment: Yes, my bad, frustration got the best of me and I rushed the question. Btw, do you know if it is possible to increase the thickness of the arrows ? So use \downarrow instead of \Downarrow, but make it thicker/more obvious ?

Comment: Of you draw the arrows in TikZ then yes. But here I would doubt it.